# Calcular a média de todos os registros de uma tabela e atualizar a coluna no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso fazer uma Query que passe em todos os registros da tabela e atualize a coluna rate_general (essa coluna é a media das notas de rate_food + rate_service + rate_price + rate_environment / 4 ) de cada registro, como fazer isso ? são 20 mil registros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: deste jeito: `Update reviews set rate_general=(rate_food + rate_service + rate_price + rate_environment) / 4  where <critério>`

Comment: qual seria o criterio ? lembrando de a media de cada registro é diferente

Comment: se você quer atualizar todos, não tem critério. basta usar essa `query` ai sem o `where`. Fazer o velho `update sem where`.

Comment: Evite colocar imagens nas perguntas, dificulta a responder por não ser possível copiar o código para testar. Muita gente tem "preguiça" de analisar perguntas com imagens.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html uma solução pode ser criar esta coluna de média como virtual calculada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar uma procedure que atualiza a tabela com base na média dos registros, para calcular os registros você pode usar a função avg, vou deixar aqui a baixo dois links sobre procedures e avg:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/stored-procedures-no-mysql/29030
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_avg.asp

Espero que tenha ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o cálculo de média no seu update, porém se o seu campo for tipo inteiro a média irá ignorar as casas decimais, por esse motivo estou adicionando um **CAST AS DECIMAL** para seu campo de média considerar as casas decimais.

```
UPDATE 
   SET rate_general = CAST((rate_food + rate_service + rate_price + rate_environment) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) / 4
```

Não se esqueça de adicionar a cláusula **WHERE** caso queira adicionar algum filtro para atualizar os registros.

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se pode ajudar, mas existe uma função no mysql chamada `avg`, ela faz a média dos seus registros

Comment: AVG é uma função de agregação de registros (como você mesmo disse). No caso do AP, é a média usando os dados de algumas colunas para um registro . O AVG não se aplica nesse caso.